# Radeon HD5570 HDMI Video Card 5.1 Audio doesn't work

Tags: sound, xbmc, hd-video

I am using Ubuntu and XMBC on my HTPC and have chosen the Radeon HD5570 Video card which has an HDMI output. In the sound preferences there is no surround sound option for the video card just stereo and although I can get sound through it in XBMC, my receiver does not state Dolby Digital on movies that are in fact Dolby so its definitely not giving me the true sound it should.

Does this card not support surround sound through HDMI and I somehow missed it? If that is the case does anyone have suggestion that has been tested and works? Id like to know its going to work before investing in yet another video card.

**UPDATE**

I purchased a Nvidia GeForce GTS 450, plugged it in, downloaded the proprietary driver from the system control panel, disabled the onboard audio from the BIOS (not sure if this was necessary but I did it anyways), and changed the sound settings to use the new video card. Everything works flawlessly. It was a seemless setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AMD's tech support, AMD graphics cards do not offer drivers for linux to allow 5.1 or 7.1 sound through HDMI. So stereo is the best i'll be able to get with this video card. Nvidia cards are better supported with linux so I will likely end up going with another card.

I'll update this with specifics when I get a new card working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I have full surround on my AMD Radeon HD 5450 7.1 on an Ubuntu based system, all over HDMI.

I'm running XBMC over this.

Results of aplay -l should give you the HDMI hardware location, after which you specify the sound to go over that.  aplay -L will give you a more detailed list.  Then specify your sound to output to that card (eg, hw:1,3 or plughw:1,3)